# Is there duplicate declaration optimisation in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, optimization

I'm getting a bit OCD and want to get rid of this:

```
const idSet = new Set(ids)
```

when I only use it to pass it to two different functions as a parameter.

I want to be able to just `new Set(ids)` twice, once for each function call but I'm not sure whether the V8 engine (I'm running the code on Node.js) will optimise this. It only needs to create one Set (also the functions I'm passing the Set to do not modify the Set in any way).

Does anybody know:

a) whether the optimisation does happen.
b) what people do to check that it actually does happen (just out of curiosity).

Thanks

**Edit:**

What I was fussing over:

```
// I wanted to change something like this:
const idSet = new Set(ids)
const r1 = fn1(idSet)
const r2 = fn2(idSet)
// to this:
const r1 = fn1(new Set(ids))
const r2 = fn2(new Set(ids))
```

Now that I think about it, probably there's some higher-order function pattern which does something like this (or I could write one... but that would defeat the original purpose of less code):

```
const [r1, r2] = hof([fn1, fn2], new Set(ids))
```

More justification: `ids` is an array. I needed it to be a Set for `fn1` and `fn2` but the calling code has no need for it to be a set and I don't want an extra variable `idSet` lying around when I'm only using `ids` there... but if the runtime creates 2 separate Sets... that's a waste so it stays.

Comment: I don't get it. Why do you want to create two sets but only want to create one set?

Comment: I see. Don't fear local variables, they're cheap and help with clarity :-) If it is the global scope, use an IIFE: `const [r1, r2] = (idSet => [fn1(idSet), fn2(idSet)])(new Set(ids));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is nothing like [hash consing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_consing) implemented in V8. Which would be pretty complicated given that JS objects (including `Set`s) are mutable by default.

In your case, just instantiate the set only once and assign it to two different variables. Or even store it as a property right on the `ids` object if that is what the two parts of your program share, without sharing a scope.